# add different value to input on click to div

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, onclick, addeventlistener

How add the value to input field according with amount client click?For each divs with different amount should  take 50, 100,200,500 value to input field onclick event. I've try implement with pure js. It's possible on jquery too

```
 <form>
 <div class="form-row">
   <label>Donate</label>
      <div class="doner-prices">50</div>
      <div class="doner-prices">100</div>
      <div class="doner-prices">200</div>
      <div class="doner-prices">500kr</div>
  </div>
 <fieldset class="form-row">
    <div class="form-col doner-price">
       <label for="donate-price">
         eller angiv dit eget
        <input type="text" id="donate-price" name="name"   pattern="\d+" value="" required>

        </label>
    </div>
    </fieldset>
   </form>   

   document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
var amount_list = document.querySelectorAll('.form-row .doner-      prices'); //node-list
var amount_array = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(".form-row   .doner-prices")); //node-list to array
var donerForm = document.getElementById('doner-hidden');
var inputDonateField = document.getElementById('donate-price');
var inputNumber = /^[0-9]+$/;
var onClickFormVisible = function () {
    donerForm.style.display = "block";
};
var onInputTypeNumber = function () {
    if (inputNumber.test(inputDonateField.value)) {
        donerForm.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        return false;
    }
};
//onclick event for each amount images
var amoutn_array = amount_array.map(function (e) {
    return e.addEventListener('click', onClickFormVisible, false);
});
//input event only if value === number
inputDonateField.addEventListener("keyup", onInputTypeNumber, false);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use below code to achieve your requirement.

```js
$(".doner-prices").click(function(){
  $("#donate-price").val($(this).attr("data-amount"));
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
 <div class="form-row">
   <label>Donate</label>
      <div data-amount="50" class="doner-prices">50</div>
      <div data-amount="100" class="doner-prices">100</div>
      <div data-amount="200" class="doner-prices">200</div>
      <div data-amount="500kr" class="doner-prices">500kr</div>
  </div>
 <fieldset class="form-row">
    <div class="form-col doner-price">
       <label for="donate-price">
         eller angiv dit eget
        <input type="text" id="donate-price" name="name"   pattern="\d+" value="" required>

        </label>
    </div>
    </fieldset>
   </form>
```

Comment: can I use it with data- atribute inside div, for exemple data-amount="50"?

Comment: Yes you can!! I have updated my answer. Please mark as answer, if you are okay with my answer then.

Comment: it's also work, what is differents?var onClickAmountFormVisible = function() {
                $(inputDonateField).val($(this).data('amount'));
                donerForm.style.display = "block";
            };

Comment: use .data or .attr